# Python - if statement makes something two times

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

while True:
    print('Welcome to the world of Daareven.')
    print('1 - New game, 2 - Exit')
    #PROBLEM STARTS HERE
    try:
        answer = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        answer = input()
    #PROBLEM ENDS HERE
    if type(answer) is str or answer > 2:
        print('Wrong input, please try again')
        continue
    elif answer == 1:
        print('Great, let\'s begin')
        break
    elif answer == 2:
        print('See you soon!')
        sys.exit()
```

Hey, I'm currently learning Python and I decided to make simple game project just for fun/learning and here's my question: when I enter string as an answer, why it forces me to make it two times before my program displays that I should try again?

Comment: With what input do you get that? What input works as you expect?

Comment: When I enter integers it works fine, but when I enter string and hit enter i must do it again before it displays 'Wrong input, please try again'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems lies here:

```
try:
    answer = int(input())
except ValueError:
    answer = input()
```

You are asking two times for input. You can just remove the second input:

```
try:
    answer = int(input())
except ValueError:
    answer = 3 # Invalid input

if answer > 2:
```

Comment: @usr2564301 Right, I changed it.

Comment: Can you add a comment on that line indicating it's a *deliberate* "wrong" value? That makes its purpose more clear. 

Comment: Yeah, just changed it and it works, thank you too :) In the except I just printed that it's wrong input and enter continue to make it back to the start of while loop :)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, because you're calling `input()` (that's one), then you typecast that to `int`, raising an exception and calling `input()` again.